# 'Bumping' Stale / Unanswered questions (and their asker!)

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, etiquette

In the quest to work through the backlog of unanswered questions it is apparent that some of the questions are complicated, 'exotic', or very involved. For example, this question: [Vertex Buffer Object (VBO) multi-class implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/34061/i-know-i-set-up-my-vbo-vba-and-indices-wrong-currently-runs-but-slowly) involves graphics acceleration with Java and OpenGL. (Here is an older example, C++ and OpenGL: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6416/is-there-something-wrong-with-my-cleanup-code-opengl-sdl )

It struck me that, for the old questions where an 'easy' answer is not available, it may be worth 'bumping' or 'nudging' the asker to see if they have a solution/answer to their own problems. It's been months since they asked, and maybe something has changed.

What is the etiquette for commenting on a zombie question saying:

> If you have found an answer to your own question it would be beneficial to the community if you could provide some details of your answer here on Code Review. You are always welcome to answer to your own question!

This way we can maybe nudge some zombies back in to the present tense (they will get an e-mail, etc. or a notification on any of the SE sites).

I have, in fact, commented on that question, so this is a 'easier to ask forgiveness than permission' sort of thing...

Comment: In some cases shouldn't the bump also suggest moving the question to a more appropriate SE community, and how to achieve that move? The Vbo/vba case is a good example, the question is actually about optimization of an algorithm that would be more likely to get a good answer on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would bring some feedback here... I have 'bumped' a couple of questions, and here is a response:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/36640/31503

In this case, I think the answer is not very descriptive, but, it exists, and has produced some follow-up discussion

I have not had any negative feedback from these attempts, so, when appropriate, I will continue with 'bumping'.

Comment: It would be nice to have that comment embedded in the answer, just in case the comment ever leaves.  I know it's been there for a while, but it just feels weird deriving your answer entirely from a comment and expecting everyone to see it (if it does stay intact).